# Dedicated database vps

Tags: mysql, vps, database

I've bought some vpses on the same data center. Unfortunately, the provider don't offer internal ip's. I only have the server public Ip and gateway (same gateway).

If I setup the mysql server alone within a vps, how can I make the communication between web and this server in a secure and fast manner?

Comment: Use another provider ?

Comment: I can't convince the customer to do it :(

Comment: You don't need to convince a customer. Just present them with the costs, pros, and cons of each option, let them decide themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most or perhaps all databases will offer encrypted connections. You can secure the connection using TLS. That may be sufficient for you. You haven't said what database you're using so we can't offer more advice. Here's the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html) on encrypted connections.

Alternately you could set up a VPN between the machines, and run either encrypted or unencrypted database connections over the VPN. If you encrypt over a VPN that's double encryption, which is probably unnecessary, "to be sure to be sure".

Depending on your data, you may not even need encrypted connections. That's not very likely though, as users, email addresses, and hashed password strings probably all need to be encrypted in transit.

You could also consider changing providers.

Comment: Thank's. Do you think I will have a slow connection using the VPN, even if the servers are in the same location?

Comment: A VPN will add latency and reduce bandwidth, but it's impossible to say how much without testing. Lightly loaded servers probably wouldn't make much difference, but if they're busy enough you need two servers, it might. It might depend on routing too, hopefully they're less than 1ms apart.

Comment: I use openvpn among all my servers in a certain sketchy cloud provider's network (something that I have to use for one legacy system).  Disable compression, use UDP encapsulation, and you will not really notice that it's there, even if systems are < 1ms apart.  (They also individually connect to services in my real networks with openvpn... never a performance issue).